# Contract name same as namespace name, a big deal?

Tags: c#, wcf

Is it a big deal for using same name for solution, namespace and WCF service ?

This is the structure of project I have,

```
Solution Fruits (7 projects)
  Fruits.Project1
  Fruits.Project2
  ....
  Fruits.Internal.WebServices
   IFruits.cs
   Fruits.cs

web.config
```

**web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Fruits.Internal.WebServices.FruitsJuicer" behaviorConfiguration="myBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Fruits.Internal.WebServices.IFruitsJuicer" bindingConfiguration="tooty_BasicHttpBinding"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>

    <bindings>  and so on....


  <service name="Fruits.Internal.WebServices.Fruits"
```

In browser i am getting this error

**The contract name 'Fruits.Internal.WebServices.Fruits' could not be found in the list of contracts implemented by the service 'Fruits'.**

The 'name' attribute is invalid - The value 'Fruits.Internal.WebServices.Fruits' is invalid according to its datatype 'serviceNameType' - The Enumeration constraint failed.

**Service Code**

```
namespace Fruits.Internal.WebServices
{
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class FruitsJuicer
    {
        public void GetFruitJuice(Details d)
        {
            typedDataAccess da = new typedDataAccess();
            da.AddRequest(d);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in short, no. People do it all the time.

Comment: Any chance you could post your service?

Comment: added it now as you said, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is generally not considered good practice to name classes the same as the namespace - for one thing you wind up having to qualify your classes in code more often as the compiler can't tell the difference between the namespace and the class.

Additionally, you might want to think about the sense of your naming and name things according to their function.  I know your example above is contrived, however, e.g.:

```
Solution Fruits (7 projects)
  Fruits.Project1
  Fruits.Project2
  ....
  Fruits.Internal.WebServices
   IFruitJuicer.cs
   FruitJuicer.cs  //Methods for juicing fruits.  
                   //Just calling it Fruits is a bit generic.
```

---

To actually answer your initial question, your class (`Fruits`) does not implement your interface (`IFruits`).  Change like so:

```
public class FruitsJuicer :IFruits
{
    public void GetFruitJuice(Details d)
    {
        typedDataAccess da = new typedDataAccess();
        da.AddRequest(d);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks paddy, but I am not able to understand the reason of the warning and error I am getting, even if compiler can't identify them, it may use the hierarchy

Comment: I changed it to fruit juicer I am still getting the same warning and error

Comment: See kha's comment on your question - can you post your service code?

Comment: For a second i even thought that is the problem but then it flied away from my mind, grrrrrr, thanks though